# Axios post not passing body parameters

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, axios

I am trying to post to an endpoint written in .NET Core, and it works when I hardcode the body parameters:

```
        var thisworks= {
            contact: {
                name: "test",
                phone: "07921212121"
            },
            timeSlotID: 3,
            date: "2020-10-01",
            description: "demo2dddd"
        }

        axios.post(
            'https://localhost:5001/api/v1/Book',
            thisworks,
            {
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then...
```

But when I try to populate the values with props and React input ref, the body would not be passed through:

```
        userName = React.createRef();
        userPhone = React.createRef();
        userDescription = React.createRef();
...

        const appointmentTime = this.props.location.appointmentTime;

        var bookingParameters = {
            contact: {
                name: this.userName.current.value,
                phone: this.userPhone.current.value
            },
            timeSlotID: appointmentTime.timeSlotID,
            date: appointmentTime.date,
            description: this.userDescription.current.value
        }

        console.log(bookingParameters);  <-- the JSON has definitely been constructed with values in it

        axios.post(
            'https://localhost:5001/api/v1/Book',
            bookingParameters ,
            {
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then...
```

[Endpoint showing Body is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfLQg.png)

Appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: You probably have another call on this endpoint somewhere, nothing seems wrong in your `axios` call

Comment: @kigiri What you mean by another call? It hits the breakpoint on that endpoint when I run my React app. And it works with the hardcoded object which proves its talking to the endpoint fine

Comment: Hi, did you try using Fiddler? Fiddler is a development proxy that you run on your machine and shows all HTTP requests and responses. You can even grab the request that was generated and try to submit it manually to try to figure out the issue.

Comment: What is your `appointmentTime`?How did you define that?Check the bookingParameters should be like below:`contact: {name: "dfgdfg", phone: "dfgdfg"}
date: "2020-10-01"
description: "dfgdfg"
timeSlotID: 1`   Be sure the timeSlotID should be int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem is due to the axios call being made in the constructor, along with the initiation of data.

The axios call that is using the body data must have got executed before the data object was fully initiated. This must have caused the observed problem.

**How to fix the problem?**

**Step 1:**  Create a constructor to initialise the state of the component.

**Step 2:** Write a function to update state when the user updates input.

**Step 3:**  Call axios from a handleSubmit() method that gets invoked when user clicks the 'submit' button of the form.

**Working code snippet:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

export default class AxiosDemo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name : "",
            phone : "",
            description : ""
        }
    }
  

  onNameChanged = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onPhoneChanged = e => {
    this.setState({
      phone: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onDescriptionChanged = e => {
    this.setState({
      description: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const data = {
          name: this.state.name,
          phone: this.state.phone,
          description: this.state.description
      }

      axios.post("https://api-url-here", data)
           .then(res => console.log(res))
           .catch(err => console.log(err)) 
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                   <input value={this.state.name}
                          onChange={this.onNameChanged} 
                          required />
                   <input value={this.state.phone}
                          onChange={this.onPhoneChanged} 
                          required />
                   <textarea value={this.state.description}
                             onChange={this.onDescriptionChanged}
                             required />
                   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
               </form>
           </div>
      )
   }
}
```

---

**More information:**   https://reactgo.com/react-post-request-axios/

Comment: Apologies I should have made this clearer. My Axios call is in a form submission handler function, values such as userName (this.userName.current.value) will be coming from user input. Hence I can't have the Axios call in ComponentDidMount. Are there any alternatives for my case? Thanks

Comment: This is a perfectly valid solution for anyone who comes across this. Although after hours of try and error I realized my issue was that for whatever reason the hyphens in my date field were invalid (date: "2020-09-26"), I ended up splitting by hyphen and concatenated back the date string and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know at all about .NET, but, I think you are passing wrong variable? Your backend looking for `bookingRecordRequest` but you are passing `bookingParameters`. Try to match the variable name first. If the problem still occurs, try pass the body payload like this:

```
axios.post(
            'https://localhost:5001/api/v1/Book',
            { bookingRecordRequest },
            {
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then...
```